# How to create a table in qt with SQLite?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt, qt-creator

I have a property of class named m_database.

```
class SqlThread : public QThread
{
public:
SqlThread();
void run();

private:
QSqlDatabase   m_database;
QString        m_dbfilename;
};
```

and i instantiate in constructor like the example below:

```
SqlThread::SqlThread()
{
 m_database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
}
```

And i create database in run function, like that (The m_dbFileName i created with other class):

```
    m_database.setDatabaseName(m_dbfilename);

    if (!m_database.open())
    {
        qWarning("%s", m_database.lastError().text().toLocal8Bit().data());
        return;
    }

    QSqlQuery databaseQuery(m_database);
    databaseQuery.prepare("CREATE TABLE data (id int not null primary key, tu text, data BLOB, puits integer);");

    if (!databaseQuery.exec())
    {
        qWarning("%s", databaseQuery.lastError().text().toLocal8Bit().data());
        return;
    }
```

Why i receive error message: **No query Unable to fetch row** ??

Comment: I am really confuse, because sometimes the function works and other times no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the query string to:

```
databaseQuery.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id int not null primary key, tu text, data BLOB, puits integer);");
```

Otherwise the execution fails if the table already exists.